# Android - Add views to item in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, android-cursoradapter

**What I want**: I have a listview which lists all the entries of my sqlite database. The database contains all the items that a number of people have bought at a supermarket, so the listview displays all the items in the database. Now, an item can be shared by many users (infact the app is about to split the costs of a receipt) and I want that the names of who are going to shared that particular item must be displayed under that item in the listview.

Result using cursoradapter in a common way:

1) row1 item quantity price 
2) row2 item quantity price 
3) row3 item quantity price 
4) ...

Resul I want:

1) row1 item quantity price 
 name 1 
 name 2 
 2) row2 item quantity price 
 name 4 
 name 7
 3) row3 item quantity price
 name 2 
 4) ...

name rows are the textviews(http://pastebin.com/hzLPPV6B) I want do add

**What I have tried to do**:

- bindView method of my CursorAdapter http://pastebin.com/4839LMq3
- layout where the listview is http://pastebin.com/uVhy3GqN
- layout of the single item in the listview http://pastebin.com/srsm7SRS
- layout of the textviews(with the name) to add under the right item in the list view http://pastebin.com/hzLPPV6B

**What the problem is**: The problem is that the bindview method doesn't work as I expected and the app starts to display infinite(I think) number of person name textview(3rd pastebin link) under each item in the list(not only the persons names I wanted).

This is the that part of the code inside bindView which I am not sure about:

```
LinearLayout itemBuyersLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.itemBuyersReceipt);
ArrayList<String> buyersName = dbManager.getBuyersNameOfItem(receiptId, cursorAdapter.getItemId(cursor.getPosition()));
for (int i=0;i<buyersName.size();i++) {
       itemBuyersLinearLayout.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.receipt_item_buyer_receipt, itemBuyersLinearLayout, false));
       TextView buyerNameTextView = (TextView) itemBuyersLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.itemBuyerReceipt);
       buyerNameTextView.setText(buyersName.get(i));
}
```

I don't know what I have to do/where I need to add some code to add that extra information

Answer (score 0):

When you are using CursorAdapter, the bindView method is used to bind data to a single row item and it does that for all rows. And what you are doing here is that you have a for loop that you use to bind all the data to a single row item.

I'm not sure how your database is set up, but you should bind it in a format like this:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.YOUR_ROW_ITEM_XML, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView buyerNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemBuyerReceipt);
    String buyerName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("YOUR_BUYER_NAME_COLUMN"));
    buyerNameTextView.setText(buyerName);
}
```

Hope that can solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: No, What I want to do is loading extra information under each row in the listview, I already bind some information (in the way you have described), but I also need to add some textviews(http://pastebin.com/hzLPPV6B) extacly under each row in the list like this: <br/>
1) row1 item quantity price <br/>
  name 1 <br/>
  name 2 <br/>
2) row2 item quantity price <br/>
  name 4 <br/>
  name 7<br/>
3) row3 item quantity price<br/>
  name 2 <br/>
4)  ...

Comment: Sorry for that bad editing but I have not been able to make a new line

Comment: If you are still solving this problem, it'll help if you can post the results you're having now with the code in your post above, like how you are doing it with "result I want" and "result using cursoradapter in a common way". Might not be able to solve it but it will give me and others who try to help a better understanding of the problem.